# Specify package of MXML file (Flex)

Tags: apache-flex, mxml

How can I specify the package of an MXML file? I can easily set the package of an ActionScript class by just wrapping it with a package declaration, but how do I do the same thing in an MXML file?

The problem I have is that I'm not able to use MXML files that are not in the same folder as the main MXML file. For structure, I want to create subfolders as such:

```
src
    mycompany
        myproject
            gui
                screens
                    Screen1.mxml
                    Screen2.mxml
                Main.mxml
```

If I want to use Screen1.mxml in Main.mxml, how do I do that? I want Screen1.mxml to be in the package "mycompany.myproject.gui.screens" but I don't know how to specify that.

If I managed to put Screen1.mxml in that package, i guess I would just use it in Main.mxml as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    xmlns:screens="mycompany.myproject.gui.screens">
    <mx:Canvas>
        <screens:Companies id="screenCompanies" />
    </mx:Canvas>
</mx:Application>
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong about that...

I'm using FlashDevelop as my IDE and building with Flex 3.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost correct. The correct namespace declaration:

```
xmlns:screens="mycompany.myproject.gui.screens.*"
```

Usage:

```
<screens:Screen1 id="screenCompanies" />
```

Comment: Thank you Timofei, but I still get an exception: "Error: Definition mycompany.myproject.gui:screens could not be found".

Comment: Is Screen.mxml automatically put in the package mycompany.myproject.gui.screens? Mustn't I specify the package in the MXML file?

Comment: Yes, it is and you mustn't. Are you sure you copied package name correctly? I see colon in your error text ...gui:screens

Comment: Nevermind, I had an import statement for mycompany.myproject.gui.screens in the ActionScript code and that was what caused the error message. Works fine when I removed that. Thank you Timofei! :)